# What units does itext use for page size and margin?

Tags: java, itext

What units does itext use for page size and margin? What is llx, lly, urx, ury?
Document document = new Document(
new RectangleReadOnly(dimension.getRectangle()),
marginLeft, 0, marginTop, 0
);

```
public RectangleReadOnly(Rectangle rect) {
    super(rect.llx, rect.lly, rect.urx, rect.ury);
    super.cloneNonPositionParameters(rect);
}

public Document(Rectangle pageSize, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The units are the PDF default user space units which default to <sup>1</sup>/<sub>72</sub> inch.

On a per-page basis this unit can be changed by setting the **UserUnit** page property:

| Key | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **UserUnit** | number | (*Optional; PDF 1.6*) A positive number that shall give the size of default user space units, in multiples of 1 ⁄ 72 inch. The range of supported values shall be implementation-dependent. Default value: *1.0* (user space unit is 1 ⁄ 72 inch). |

*(ISO 32000-2, Table 31 — Entries in a page object)*

Beware and take *The range of supported values shall be implementation-dependent* seriously - some viewers only support positive integer values, some only values >=1, some ignore it altogether.